# Creating Join to Display Values of One column from T1 which are not in T2 with some where comparisons

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause, procedures

I am trying to create join in MYSQL Stored Procedure, one table is EMployeeMaster and Other Table is WeekRest.

My join should result values of EMPID from EmpMaster for ONLY THOSE EMPIDs which EMPIDs do not exist in second Table WeekRest with some conditions. I am not able to get expected results.

Attaching Table Structures with just necessary columns and sample values for Table and the Join I have created.

1. Create Statement for First Table **hrmempmaster**

   ```
       CREATE TABLE `hrmempmaster` (
     `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `EMPID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `Department` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Designation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `ShiftName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `ShiftID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `ReportingTo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `UnitCode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `UnitName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `DivisionName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `DivisionCode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Gender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `DOB` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `DOJ` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `FatherName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `EMPID_UNIQUE` (`EMPID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```
2. Create Statement For Second Table **WeekRest**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `hrmweekrest` (
     `ID` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
     `EmpID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `EmpName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `FatherName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Department` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Designation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `WeekRestOn` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Month` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `Year` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `MonthYear` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`EmpID`,`Month`,`Year`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```
3. My Procedure which is not giving expected Values

   ```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `HRFetchWeekRest`(IN Department VARCHAR(25), IN MonthYear varchar (15))
   begin

   select hrmempmaster.empid, hrmempmaster.Name,hrmempmaster.FatherName, hrmempmaster.Department,hrmempmaster.Designation, HRMWEEKREST.WeekRestOn FROM HRMEMPMASTER

   LEFT JOIN HRMWEEKREST ON HRMEMPMASTER.EMPID = HRMWEEKREST.EMPID

   where hrmempmaster.empid not in (select empid from HRMWEEKREST where HRMWEEKREST.MonthYear = MonthYear  ) and  hrmempmaster.department = Department;

   end
   ```
4. Example

IF  EmployeeMaster table has 1 Employee with EMPID ID1, ID2, ID3...., and I pass Department as Dept1 for all employees and WeekRest table contains following Values in Columns

```
    # ID, EmpID, EmpName, FatherName, Department, Designation, WeekRestOn, Month, Year, Status, MonthYear
    1, ID1, Name1, Fname1, Dept1, Designation1, Sunday, January, 2017, Active, January2017
```

Then when

i)  Department is Passed as "Dept1" and MonthYear as "February2017"
The select statement should return ALL EMPIDs as None of then have Value in Weekrest table. Treat February as any other month in year except January

ii)  Department is Passed as "Dept1" and MonthYear as "January2017"
The select statement should return ALL EMPIDs except ID1 as except ID1 none of the IDs have Value in Weekrest table.

Will try to provide any further information at earliest

Comment: To decribe the actual problem you should reduce all that code and words drastically

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `HRFetchWeekRest`(IN Department VARCHAR(25), IN MonthYear varchar (15))
    begin

    select hrmempmaster.empid, hrmempmaster.Name,hrmempmaster.FatherName, hrmempmaster.Department,hrmempmaster.Designation, HRMWEEKREST.WeekRestOn FROM HRMEMPMASTER

    LEFT JOIN HRMWEEKREST ON HRMEMPMASTER.EMPID = HRMWEEKREST.EMPID AND HRMWEEKREST.MonthYear = MonthYear

    where HRMWEEKREST.empid  IS NULL and  hrmempmaster.department = Department;

    end
```